# Not able to target a sub property of a JSON object in react stored in state within the render method

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm pulling in JSON data from Contentful (a headless CMS). The data comes in perfectly with no issues. I'm able to do just about anything with the data as well as target it's properties. However, when in the render method I am not able to target that data past the state object level. For instance, I am able to target "this.state.story" but I am not able to target "this.state.story.sys.id" when within the render method and or within the JSX itself. Please, see the following code:

```
class Story extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
 super(props);
   this.state = {
     story: [],
     relatedStories: [],
     sid: this.props.sid,
     newSid: ""
   };
  }
componentDidMount() {
 const client = require("contentful").createClient({
  space: "xxx",
  accessToken: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
});
const getStory = async () => {
  console.log("getting the story");
  const story = await client.getEntry(this.state.sid);

  if (story) {
    console.log("got the story: ");
    this.setState([story]);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`Error getting Entries for ${this.state.sid}.`);
};

const getRelatedStories = async () => {
  let relatedStories = await client.getEntries({
    content_type: "story",
    "fields.tags[all]": "boating"
  });
  this.setState([...relstories.items]);
};
getStory();
getRelatedStories();
console.log(this.state);
}


render() {
// I am not able to target beyond this.state.story
console.log(this.state.story);//works. this returns a json object that has sys.id properties
console.log(this.state.story.sys.id) //returns TypeError: Cannot read property 'sys' of undefined
console.log(this.state.relatedStories);
return (
  <Layout meta={meta}>
    <div className="bg-primary">
      <ul>
        {this.state.story.map(s => (
          <li>{s.sys.id}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
   </Layout>
  );
 }
}
```

Here is a sample of the JSON that is returned from Contentful:

```
{ 
 "sys":{ 
  "space":{  },
  "id":"1DF3FzEtJkeG9Xfuhq01SG",
  "type":"Entry",
  "createdAt":"2019-12-20T21:17:03.735Z",
  "updatedAt":"2020-01-03T10:36:59.844Z",
  "environment":{  },
  "revision":4,
  "contentType":{  },
  "locale":"en-US"
 },
 "fields":{  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `getStory` setState to this:

```
if (story) {
    console.log("got the story: ");
    this.setState({story: [story]});
    return;
  }
```

The way you had it was overwriting your entire state with an array that included the story.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think both of your `setState()` need reworking, as there seems to be a mismatch of types.

```
const getStory = async () => {
  console.log("getting the story");
  const story = await client.getEntry(this.state.sid);

  if (story) {
    console.log("got the story: ");
    this.setState({
      story: [{ ...story }],
    });
    return;
  }
  console.log(`Error getting Entries for ${this.state.sid}.`);
};

const getRelatedStories = async () => {
  let relatedStories = await client.getEntries({
    content_type: "story",
    "fields.tags[all]": "boating"
  });
  this.setState({ 
    relatedStories: [...relstories.items],
  });
};
```

You should be assigning the responses from both requests to the respective properties within your state.

Comment: wndtjun thanks! Im hacking this code in everyway possible! I fixed the setState issues. However, the real problem is when I try to target the state more than 3 levels deep. For instance, I am able to target this.state.anything but when I target this.state.anything.deeper I get the dreaded "Cannot read property 'deeper' of undefined" where I guarentee you, by looking at console.log as well as react dev tools the entire JSON object is there in state along with all of its nested properties and values.

Comment: @ilanlyfe hmmm.. it seems like you are trying to read something that is undefined. Are those optional fields?